# Button not linking to input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, button, if-statement, input

I want the button to run the code in the corresponding function field, but I don't believe I have it set up correctly. The string or numbers entered in the field should be processed and then the answer should be printed out. The last 'else' statement is simply to see if it runs the code, which it did, but I could enter both numbers and strings and the first statement would be printed "This is not a year". I also am not sure that I formatted the second 'else/if' statements parameters of (enter % 4 && enter % 100 && !enter % 400) correctly. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried to resolve this on my own and have progressed slowly, so any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--leap year calculator-->
    <h3>Is it a leap year?</h3>

    <form action="">
        Year:<input type="text" name="enter" id="enter"> <br>
    </form>
    <script>function YOLO(enter){
    if (iNaN(enter)){
    console.log("This is not a year");
    }
    else if (enter % 4 && enter % 100 && !enter % 400){console.log("no");
    }
    else if(enter % 4){console.log("yes");
    }
    else {alert("working")}
    };

    var Id= document.getElementById("enter");
    </script>
    <button onclick="YOLO(Id)">Enter</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You have syntax error in your code, I think you want to use function `isNaN`. You used `iNaN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must work with `value` property of element. Something like this:

```
<button onclick="YOLO(document.getElementById('enter').value);">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem and my syntax error. Although in a previous set of code I had fixed 'iNaN' to 'isNaN' but for some reason it disappeared and I did not catch it again. Thanks again.

Comment: Although my function still does not execute properly, is the code formatted correctly for the second `if/else` statement?

Comment: @user2319588 Your code is valid javascript function by syntax, but the function process it must do, I don't know.